# how to assign an "id" to a RadioButtonGroup using actionscript?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

lets say i have a

```
var rdGroup:RadioButtonGroup = new RadioButtonGroup();
```

how can i assign the id

```
rdGroup.id = "id_RdGroup";
```

and how can i add this group inside a VBox say

```
var vbBox:VBox = new VBox();
 vbBox.addElement(rdGroup);
```

this thing gives error. that property id not found... any solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*id* is an mxml property which lets you define the name of the object you're creating. So, more or less,

```
<mx:Button id="myButton" />
```

is the same as this pseudocode:

```
public var myButton:Button = new Button();
this.addChild(myButton);
```

The MXML defined objects are a shortcut. If you don't define the *id* property (because you will not need to reference a given object in your code) it will be created by the compiler, which chooses an unique name.

That's why there's no *id* property of the objects and you can't assign it. The *id* in MXML is the name of your variable in actionscript.

If you're trying to keep handles to more than one variable by String you will need to keep a list of them in some form, one possible solution would be:

```
var myGroups:Object = new Object();
var rdGroup:RadioButtonGroup = new RadioButtonGroup();
myGroups["id_RdGroup"] = rdGroup;
[...]
vbBox.addElement( myGroups["id_RdGroup"]);
```